# How to make ubuntu not ask for password after login

Tags: login, password

I'm not trying to delete my password or anything. I just want ubuntu to remember my password after I login as an admin user and use that when installing/removing software or running sudo commands. The non-admin users should be prompt for the admin password though. Is there a way to do that and if so why doesn't ubuntu do that as default?

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as "an admin password" in Ubuntu. Any user can elevate his privileges by using sudo as long as that is available to him. And by default `sudo` requires you to re-authenticate for security reasons. This is a sane default for this reasons as it fits with the "secure by default" policy.

However, it does remember it for a short period of time. Here's a question on how: [How does sudo remember you already entered root's password?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/37299/23363)

Several options to go from here:

- **Passwordless sudo**

  From the manpage of `sudoers(5)`:

  > By default, `sudo` requires that a user authenticate him or herself before running a command. This behavior can be modified via the `NOPASSWD` tag.

  Just change the lines in `/etc/sudoers` to include this. E.g.:

  ```
  %admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL
  %sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
  ```

  becomes

  ```
  %admin  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
  %sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
  ```
- **Extend timeout**

  By default `sudo` will "remember" your password to elevate your privileges again for fifteen minutes. You can extend this to a much longer time, let's say a day. Do note that this is not unlocked on login, but only triggered the first time you are elevating your privileges.

  To extend this, edit the `/etc/sudoers` file and locate the line

  ```
  Defaults        env_reset
  ```

  and append `,timestamp_timeout=1440` to it so it becomes

  ```
  Defaults        env_reset,timestamp_timeout=1440
  ```

  Alternatively, use `-1` (a negative value) to have a really indefinite timeout. Read more about this on the [Ubuntu Community wiki: RootSudoTimeout](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudoTimeout).

Important note! Editing the `/etc/sudoers` file should be done with great care. Incorrect syntax will result in a system on which you are probably not be able to elevate your privileges again and you'll have to perform a rather complicated password recovery. To edit it safely, use the `sudo visudo` command in the terminal. It will not directly write to the file, but only when you exit and save it and the syntax is correct. This will prevent a lot of trouble.

Comment: I'd like to just point out that there is a reason for why the password prompt is there, and that by disabling it, you're effectively removing critical parts of the security layer - and that this shouldn't be done on any kind of production machine.

Comment: What I wanted was to be asked for password at only login screen and never after that point. You are saying it is not possible?

Comment: maybe possible, but certainly not adviseable

Answer (score 0):

In your system settings - little gear icon in right top corner - you can open *Users*.
Click on the user you want to modify for the passwordless login.
In the settings dialogue you can change the setting *automatic login*.

Comment: I don't think this is a login setting to change as I think OP is asking for a way to have an indefinite sudo password remember time.

Comment: But it's this answer that other people may have looked for, when searching Google for `ubuntu automatic login` ;) It's this answer that I was looking for, at any rate.